# Change the delay from 20 to 1 minutes

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

> Quotes are not sourced from all markets and may be delayed up to 20
>   minutes. Information is provided 'as is' and solely for informational
>   purposes, not for trading purposes or advice.

This advice appears when I use `GOOGLEFINANCE()` function in my spreadsheet. It is unfortunate that the data is delayed up to 20 minutes.

What is the best way to get real-time stock prices? Suppose my budget is around $50 per month.

Be aware that I trade only US equities, i.e. no bonds, no cryptocurrencies, and so on.

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample version of my portfolio spreadsheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hIfCuupmc_OZ6514DXFe_NrDCX1Ix6tcvySP_VolppI/edit#gid=42667785. It would be important for me to get the price in real-time, and not delayed by maximum 20 minutes.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The GOOGLEFINANCE formula is **not consistent with the delays**. Different stocks can be delayed by different times. You can get an estimate of the delay by using `GOOGLEFINANCE("TICKER","DATADELAY")`.

This is at least somewhat helpful, but not ideal, because you'll have a price on your sheet and you don't know exactly when the price was from, just an estimate of how old the price might be. And forget about pre-market or after-hours. Once the market closes, all bets are off you'll have no idea when the price is from (i.e. after hours quote or regular session close).

If you want accurate real-time quotes, **you're going to need an add-on**. You said your budget is $50. That doesn't leave you a lot of options. For $9 per month you can use the [Market Data Add-on](https://www.marketdata.app/sheets-addon/) and get real-time stock prices along with historical intraday prices. There is also a free tier that gives you 100 free daily prices.

Market Data's STOCKDATA formula is a drop-in replacement for GOOGLEFINANCE, so it follows the same syntax. It will accomplish what you need. For example, `STOCKDATA("SPY","ALL")` will produce an output like this:

| Date | Bid | Bid Size | Mid | Ask | Ask Size | Last | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/19/2022 9:09:48 | 388.36 | 1400 | 388.38 | 388.41 | 1400 | 388.37 | 2715229 |

Note that the date and time of the quote is included in the output, so you know exactly when the quote was fetched. There is no doubt as to whether the quote is coming from the previous day or whether it is a quote from the pre-market session (which is the case of this example). If you compare to the current time using `NOW()`, you'll find the Market Data quotes are delayed by about 1-2 seconds, which is due to network latency from your Google Sheet to the servers.

Answer (score 0):

it's important to notice the word "may" in the first sentence:

> ...and **may be delayed** up to 20 minutes...

usually, it's way under 20 minutes (around 1 - 1:30 minutes), but there could be times when some delay may occur.

and to answer your question: no, it's not possible to force it under 1 minute

if you want to go full pro mode with Google Sheets then try: **[`=CRYPTOFINANCE()`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cryptofinance/bhjnahcnhemcnnenhgbmmdapapblnlcn?utm_source=permalink)**

Comment: What is the difference between the "pro mode" and the standard mode? What is the difference between "CRYPTOFINANCE()" AND "GOOGLEFINANCE()"? Is "CRYPTOFINANCE()" for the cryptocurrencies?

Comment: the difference is that you pay for pro mode. cryptofinance includes cryptocurrencies but it can handle all the googlefinance job. it all depends on what exactly you want to do. cryptofinance includes a lot of stuff that is for free too and instant (no need to worry on 20min delay). for example, if you want to lookup some historical events you are limited on 10 calls per day with cryptofinance unless you pay 35$ per month. like I said it all depends on what exactly you wanna do...

Comment: It is quite confusing to get the pro mode with Google Sheets. Can you guide me so that I can get realtime stock prices inside my spreadsheet?

Comment: these may help: https://cryptofinance.ai/docs/getting-started-with-cryptofinance/#how-to-install - https://cryptofinance.ai/data-availability-service - https://medium.com/cryptofinance-ai/how-to-get-bitcoin-and-other-cryptocurrency-prices-in-your-spreadsheet-for-free-4f6d59d1a2fd

Answer (score -1):

The documentation links from player0 indicate that ONLY crypto exchanges are supported.   Data is NOT available from stock exchanges (NASDAQ, NYSE, etc).

Comment: How does it helps the main problem ? Could you me more explicit ?